# WOL on multihomed host

Tags: linux, networking, wake-on-lan

Topology: xDSL modem <-ethernet 'wan'-> Linux Host(two NICs) <-ethernet lan'->sleeping linux ITX host. Linux host is 5.0.0-arch1-1-ARCH and ITX host is some recent LibreElec release.

Testing performed: issue wol command with MAC address of ITX host, while another host is running tcpdump on an adapter that is connected in turn to each of the two ethernet segments (there are unmanaged switches in play).

Test results: when done with only the MAC address the magic packet appears to be routed out the interface with a default route ('wan' interface obtains a default route via DHCP from ISP). Which makes sense since 255.255.255.255 would match 0.0.0.0/0. A directed subnet broadcast (example 192.168.1.255) results in the magic packet being sent out via the desired interface ('lan' interface).

Context and question: The ITX host does not respond to the directed subnet broadcast magic packets. Is there a way to influence this routing choice?

Software used: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/wol/; command is wol xx:xx:xx:xx:xx. The -i parameter when given an IP address does not result in any packet being sent ( ARP requests are observed). No successful result was yet obtained from using the directed subnet of 192.168.1.255.

Comment: Please add the command you are using to generate wol. Wol packets are never routed, are not the two machines directly connected?

Comment: Which tool or command are you using to send the WOL packet? I know of at least `etherwake` and `wakeonlan`: of those two, `etherwake` accepts the `-i <interface name>` parameter that would easily allow sending the packet out of the interface of your choice.